# How do I reset the redux-test-utils store between tests

Tags: javascript, redux, jestjs

I have a subscriber that dispatches an action based on the parameters supplied to a pub event

```
// subscriptions.js
import store from '../store';
import { action } from '../actions';
export const subscribeToToggle = () => {
    window.$.subscribe('action/toggle', (_e, isToggleOn) => {

        if (isToggleOn=== true){
            store.dispatch(action());
        }
    });
};
```

In my test file I write 2 tests that test that the action is sent only when true is supplied.

```
// subscriptions.test.js
import { subscribeToToggle } from './subscriptions';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import { actionTypes } from '../constants';
import store from '../store';
jest.mock('../store');

beforeEach(() => {
    window.$ = jQuery;
    window.$.unsubscribe('action/toggle');

});

test('Action not sent when false', () => {

    subscribeToToggleOpen();
    window.$.publish('action/toggle', false);

    expect(store.getActions().length).toBe(0);
});

test('Action sent when true', () => {

    subscribeToToggleOpen();
    window.$.publish('action/toggle', true);

    expect(store.getActions().length).toBe(1);
    expect(store.getActions()[0].type).toBe(actionTypes.ACTION);
});
```

I have the following mocked store using redux-test-utils

```
import { createMockStore } from 'redux-test-utils';
let store = null;
store = createMockStore('');
export default store;
```

The issue I face is that my test only pass when the false test comes first. If they are the other way around the 'Action not sent when false' test fails as it sees the action supplied by the 'Action sent when true' test.

Is there any way for me to use the beforeEach method to reset the mocked store object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the problem is that your store is essentially a singleton. This can create issues when you are trying to do things like this and is generally kind of an anti-pattern.

Instead of exporting a store object, it'd probably be better if you exported a `getStore()` function which could be called to get the store. In that case, you could then do:

```
getStore().dispatch(action());
```

Inside of that, you could then have other helper functions to be able to replace the store that is being returned by it. That file could look something like this:

```
import { createMockStore } from 'redux-test-utils';
let store = createMockStore('');

export default () => store;
```

Then, inside of there, you can add another which could be `resetStore` as a non-default export:

```
export const resetStore = () => store = createMockStore('');
```

It would still technically be a singleton, but it's now a singleton you can have some control over.

Then, in your `beforeEach()` in your tests, just call `resetStore()`:

```
import { resetStore } from '../store';

beforeEach(() => {
  resetStore();
});
```

This would also require you to update your real code to use `getStore()` instead of `store` directly, but it'll probably be a beneficial change in the long run.

---

Complete Updated Version:

```
// subscriptions.js
import getStore from '../store';
import { action } from '../actions';
export const subscribeToToggle = () => {
    window.$.subscribe('action/toggle', (_e, isToggleOn) => {

        if (isToggleOn=== true){
            getStore().dispatch(action());
        }
    });
};
```

---

```
// subscriptions.test.js
import { subscribeToToggle } from './subscriptions';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import { actionTypes } from '../constants';
import getStore, { resetStore } from '../store';
jest.mock('../store');

beforeEach(() => {
    window.$ = jQuery;
    window.$.unsubscribe('action/toggle');
    resetStore();
});

test('Action not sent when false', () => {
    subscribeToToggleOpen();
    window.$.publish('action/toggle', false);

    expect(getStore().getActions().length).toBe(0);
});

test('Action sent when true', () => {

    subscribeToToggleOpen();
    window.$.publish('action/toggle', true);

    expect(getStore().getActions().length).toBe(1);
    expect(getStore().getActions()[0].type).toBe(actionTypes.ACTION);
});
```

---

```
import { createMockStore } from 'redux-test-utils';
let store;

export const resetStore = () => { store = createMockStore(''); }

resetStore(); // init the store, call function to keep DRY

export default () => store;
```

---

Beyond that, the other way would be to have a global reducer which could reset the state of the store to it's default, but that would be messier and I don't really think would generally fit with writing a unit test.

Comment: Thanks, I feel like changing the nature of my store just so I can unit test it would feel bad, and in the context of the running app (rather than the tests) I would want my store to be a singleton.

So this is definitely the correct answer but for now I am going to just keep my tests in the same order

Comment: In the long run, you'll probably find issues with the pattern you are using, even without the unit tests. It's generally not a great idea to return something that you can't possibly change. You can still keep it a singleton, but have it returned via a function. Then if you need to make changes, the refactor becomes a lot less painful.